# simplifying algebraic expression with non-polynomial term

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression 
$$\sqrt{(\delta-k)s^2+(k-\lambda)s+\beta s^{\epsilon}(s-1)+\alpha}$$
where $k$, $\delta$,$\alpha$,$\lambda$ and $\beta$ are constants and ($0\leq \epsilon\leq1)$.my question is: for what values of $k$ (if any) one can write the expression under the square root as a square of other expression.

Comment: So you want the expression $(\delta-k)s^2+(k-\lambda)s+\beta s^{\epsilon}(s-1)+\alpha$ to be in the form of $(k+....)^2$?

Comment: $s$ can't go away. What do you mean you want " $k$ to be a value not a function of s"?

Comment: I am not really sure, it is a bit hard for me.